# div with some sections using fix width

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a layout like below using fix width. The width should be 600px and then I want to have some sections in the main div. And I want that the main div is aligned at the center of the page.

[image]

Im a CSS beginner and Im not achieving this result, I have a fiddle with the issues: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfv5k0y3/)

Its not aligned at the center of the page and also only the div .post-title is appearing properly.

Do you know what is necessary to achieve the image layout?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    
      <div class="post-title">
        title
      </div>
    
      <div class="post-info">
    
        <div class="post-date">
          date
        </div>
        <div class="post-admin">
          admin
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="post-category">
        category
      </div>
      
      <div class="post-tags">
      tags
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle.

Here is the CSS in case it didn't work. Using flexbox.

```
.wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  display:block;
  margin: auto;
  border:1px solid gray;
  text-align:center;
}

.post-title{
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:left;
}

.post-info{
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}

.post-date{
  border-right:1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-admin{
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
}

.post-category{
  border-top:1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
  padding:10px;
}

.post-tags{
  border-top:1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float everything, in fact it makes it very difficult to handle elements under your box because the floats get ripped from the document flow. Also the parent container no longer recognizes the size of the elements. You could instead use `flexbox` for the two elements next to each other, but for better compatibility you can also just make them `inline-block`.

I would wrap everything in another block (possibly just the body body if that works for you) with `width: 100%;` (or at least something larger than 600px) and then use `margin: 0 auto;` (0 top and bottom, auto left and right). I used `inline-block` for the date and admin blocks. Also not that you must remove the whitespace between them (I used an html comment) so they don't break.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid gray;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post-title{
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

.post-info{
  width:100%;
}

.post-date{
  border-right:1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
  width:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.post-admin{
  padding:20px;
  width:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.post-category{
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

.post-tags{
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="post-title">
      title
    </div>

    <div class="post-info">

      <div class="post-date">
        date
      </div><!--
   --><div class="post-admin">
        admin
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-category">
      category
    </div>

    <div class="post-tags">
    tags
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```